# PHP doesn't send the mail

Tags: php

I am using XAMPP and i want to send an email to one of my email adresses but it seems like it's not reaching it. What can i do ?
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "adress@example.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
}
?>
```

This is what phpinfo() returns on sendmail_path:

```
sendmail_path   \xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe    \xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of mail()? Did you check the error logs? Did you read the manual and aware of the fact that PHP is not responsible for the underlying mail delivery system's behaviour?

Comment: What he said, plus, you're obviously on Winblows, and the executable "mailtodisk.exe" doesn't send email, it writes to a file, which is usually C:\xampp\mailoutput.

You need a Real Server(tm), which will probably run a Nixen type OS.

Comment: I don't know how to check the value of mail or the error logs